# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this concat query in mysql

```
SELECT CONCAT(if(fName,fName,''),Name) 
From Student
```

Error:

> #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'

Comment: can you describe your current Student table structure?

Comment: Student=> id int ,Name varchar, fName varchar

Comment: What collations do the columns have?

Comment: no i didn't may be it'a  mysql bug

Answer (score 34):

This is due to collections difference, you can solve by converting the two strings or columns 
to one collection say **UTF8**

```
CONCAT(CAST(fName AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8),CAST('' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8))
```

This will solve :)

you can check more about casting in MySQL here [MySQL Casting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html)

Comment: The MySQL Casting link is dead, might be due to being for 5.0. Here's something similar for 8.0:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Answer (score 24):

The charsets and/or collations you use in your connection do not match the charset/collation in your table.

There are 4 solutions:

**1- Change the charset in your connection:**

```
//find out the charset used in your table.
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'student'
//set the server charset to match
SET NAMES 'charset_name' [COLLATE 'collation_name']
```

**2- Change the charset used in your table to match the server charset:**

```
//find out the charset used in the server
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
//Change the charset used in the table
ALTER TABLE student ......
```

**3- Change the default charset settings and restart MySQL**

Edit My.ini and replace the `character_set_*` options, so they match your tables.

**4- Change the charset settings for your connection**

You client can override the charset and collation settings.
If it does not option 1 or 3 should fix your issue, but if the connection overrides these settings, you need to check the connection-string and edit the charset/collation settings to match your database.

**Some advice:**

Find a charset. I recommend `UTF8` and a collation: I recommend `utf8_general_ci`. And use those consistantly everywhere.

Comment: Alternatively, in countries like Germany, you can use utf8_latin1_ci, which incorporates the german umlauts at the right position (e.g. ä after a).

Comment: @CAFEBABE, latin1 sounds like a better option for western databases.

Comment: @Johan, Sometimes you need to work with tables that has different collations and you don't have the authority to change the collations for said tables.

Comment: If user-defined functions are being called from within `concat`, it might also help to `SET NAMES [your_preferred_charset];` and then drop and redefine the procedures and functions.

Answer (score 3):

A concatenation can only work if the collation of all used values matches OR you use a collation that all collations are a subset of (from a logical standpoint).

If you want to concatenate text, each text should be the same collation. Take a look at the collation the database uses, then take a look at the collation that your connection uses:

```
show variables like '%coll%'
```

The collation_connection should match the collation of the table you try to concatenate. If it doesn't, the error message will arise.

You can then change the connection collation to match the one of the table.

Comment: Do you have some examples for "collations that all collations are a subset of"?

Answer (score 2):

Look like you have a miss use on the `if` statement there because it will resulting an `undefined` data type so the `concat` operation will fail as it different in data type. Try change the query by use `ifnull` instead.

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT concat(ifnull(fName,''),Name) From Student
```

see the demo here http://www.sqlize.com/kfy85j8f1e

for another reference read also http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,225982,225982#msg-225982

Answer (score 2):

It can also be an error with your client library being too old for the mysql server.
We had a similar problem with LIKE and the character "ő" and using PHP MySQL library version 5.1.52 but MySQL server version 5.5.22.
The problem has gone away upon upgrading the client library.

Comment: When you say client library, are you talking about the *official* `mysql` cmd client?

Comment: @Pacerier yes, the now deprecated ext/mysql one

Comment: Deprecated? Are you talking about PHP?

Comment: of course, what else? did you miss the memo about the old mysql extension getting deprecated and even removed for php7? this is not about mysqli though

Comment: I mean since when did this become a PHP question? Everyone here is talking about MySql, not C# Java or PHP.